# Single User Login in case of network/System crash

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to have single user login in my web site, i.e a user can't logi n with one userid and password from different places at same time.

It can be done simply by maintaining a flag in database and altering it on user logout and login, but what about if the user doesn't press logout button and:

1. closes the browser(here I can alter database flag through `window.unload` event)
2. network crash (real problem is here).

Can anyone suggest how to deal with system/network related problems? I don't want to use `session.end()` because sometimes it fires after a default timeout (~20 min).

Can I use signalR to create a server timer to monitor if user is alive or not?

Comment: can any one say is it possible to handle or not??

Answer (score 1):

SignalR will suffer from server crashes.  SignalR does its best to ensure that events are triggered prior to shut down but there are cases when a server dies that will result in you having invalid entries in your db.

An approach that is used by https://jabbr.net/ is it logs every user off on server start.  Therefore whenever your SignalR server starts: run cleanup on your database.  In all other situations you can rely on SignalR to track your users appropriately.

To address your #1: SignalR will actually send an abort command to the server on unload, however if that command doesn't get sent for whatever reason the server will still timeout the connection and will eventually trigger OnDisconnected on the hub.